# WebSocket Secure java.nio.channels.UnresolvedAddressException

Tags: java, android, websocket

I faced with the problem using WebSocket Secure. I using this websocket library: 'org.java-websocket:Java-WebSocket:1.3.0'. The problem appears only on LENOVO smartphones (not at all models, for example Lenovo A6000 works as expected). For example error occurs on Lenovo Vibe devices. I tested it on Nexus 4, Nexus 5, Nexus 5x, Nexus 6, Nexus 6P, Lenovo A6000, Lenovo Vibe, Samsung Galaxy SIII (CyanogenMod Android 4.4.4). Error appeared only on Lenovo Vibe devices from this list. 
Here is an error:

```
java.nio.channels.UnresolvedAddressException
```

Here is my code:

```
    final String url =  wss://*****.com/wss;
    URI uri=null;
    try{
        uri = new URI(url);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
    }
    Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
    headers.put("auth_key", TOKEN);
    mWebSocketClient = new WebSocketClient(uri, new Draft_10(), headers, 0) {
        @Override
        public void onOpen(ServerHandshake handshakedata) {

        }
        @Override
        public void onMessage(String message) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onClose(int code, String reason, boolean remote) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Exception ex) {
            //HERE I HANDLE AN ERROR ON LENOVO VIBE
        }
    };
    try{
        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getDefault();
        mWebSocketClient.setWebSocketFactory(new DefaultSSLWebSocketClientFactory(sslContext));
        mWebSocketClient.connect();
    }catch (Exception e)
    {
    }
```

Error occurs inside the library, in WebSocketClient.java class here:

```
private final void interruptableRun() {
    if( channel == null ) {
        return;// channel will be initialized in the constructor and only be null if no socket channel could be created or if blocking mode could be established
    }

    try {
        String host;
        int port ;

        if( proxyAddress != null ) {
            host = proxyAddress.getHostName();
            port = proxyAddress.getPort();
        } else {
            host = uri.getHost();
            port = getPort();
        }
        channel.connect( new InetSocketAddress( host, port ) );
        conn.channel = wrappedchannel = createProxyChannel( wsfactory.wrapChannel( channel, null, host, port ) );

        timeout = 0; // since connect is over
        sendHandshake();
        readthread = new Thread( new WebsocketWriteThread() );
        readthread.start();
    } catch ( ClosedByInterruptException e ) {
        onWebsocketError( null, e );
        return;
    } catch ( /*IOException | SecurityException | UnresolvedAddressException*/Exception e ) {//
        onWebsocketError( conn, e );
        conn.closeConnection( CloseFrame.NEVER_CONNECTED, e.getMessage() );
        return;
    }

    ByteBuffer buff = ByteBuffer.allocate( WebSocketImpl.RCVBUF );
    try/*IO*/{
        while ( channel.isOpen() ) {
            if( SocketChannelIOHelper.read( buff, this.conn, wrappedchannel ) ) {
                conn.decode( buff );
            } else {
                conn.eot();
            }

            if( wrappedchannel instanceof WrappedByteChannel ) {
                WrappedByteChannel w = (WrappedByteChannel) wrappedchannel;
                if( w.isNeedRead() ) {
                    while ( SocketChannelIOHelper.readMore( buff, conn, w ) ) {
                        conn.decode( buff );
                    }
                    conn.decode( buff );
                }
            }
        }

    } catch ( CancelledKeyException e ) {
        conn.eot();
    } catch ( IOException e ) {
        conn.eot();
    } catch ( RuntimeException e ) {
        // this catch case covers internal errors only and indicates a bug in this websocket implementation
        onError( e );
        conn.closeConnection( CloseFrame.ABNORMAL_CLOSE, e.getMessage() );
    }
}
```

On This Line:

```
channel.connect( new InetSocketAddress( host, port ) );
```

**Also, if you know any other WebSocket library that properly working on all devices, where i can use wss links and put custom headers, please share.**

Comment: It is `UnresolvedAddressException`. Please spell error messages and class names accurately. It is very confusing. The compiler won't accept the mistake: why should we?

Comment: I know that it is "UnresolvedAddressException"   exception.getMessage(); method returns null so how can i give you "error messages"?? "class names accurately"? Error Occurs in WebSocketClient.java in channel.connect( new InetSocketAddress( host, port ) );
 line. Also, websocket link is correct - because it works on all other devices(Nexus 4, 5, 5x, 6, 6p, Samsung Galaxy S III (CyanogenMod Android 4.4)).

Comment: @EJP so why you down voted my question? This is really a bug that i found on Lenovo Vibe devices, and FIXED it, unlike you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found a solution.. and here it is:

1) Rewrite WebSocketClient.java class from the libraty (or just extract the library and paste it to your project)

2) Create new class:

```
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;

public class MyInetSocketAddress {

    public static InetSocketAddress myInetSocketAddress(String hostname, int port, boolean needResolved) 
    {
        if (hostname == null || port < 0 || port > 65535) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("host=" + hostname + ", port=" + port);
        }
        InetAddress addr = null;
        if (needResolved) {
            try {
                addr = InetAddress.getByName(hostname);
            } 
            catch (Exception ignored) 
            {
            }
        }
        return new InetSocketAddress(addr, port);
    }

}
```

3) Open your WebSocketClient.java class, find:

> interruptableRun()

method and replace this:

> channel.connect( new InetSocketAddress( host, port ) );

with this one:

> channel.connect( MyInetSocketAddress.myInetSocketAddress(host, port, true) );

4) Also add try/catch at the end of the method - replace:

> conn.closeConnection( CloseFrame.ABNORMAL_CLOSE, e.getMessage() );

with:

```
try{
    conn.closeConnection( CloseFrame.ABNORMAL_CLOSE, e.getMessage() );
}
catch (Exception e1)
{
}
```

5) As additional add catch(Exception e) here:

```
private class WebsocketWriteThread implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Thread.currentThread().setName( "WebsocketWriteThread" );
        try {
            while ( !Thread.interrupted() ) {
                SocketChannelIOHelper.writeBlocking( conn, wrappedchannel );
            }
        } catch ( IOException e ) {
            conn.eot();
        } catch ( InterruptedException e ) {
            // this thread is regularly terminated via an interrupt
        }
    }
}
```

like shown here:

```
private class WebsocketWriteThread implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Thread.currentThread().setName( "WebsocketWriteThread" );
        try {
            while ( !Thread.interrupted() ) {
                SocketChannelIOHelper.writeBlocking( conn, wrappedchannel );
            }
        } catch ( IOException e ) {
            conn.eot();
        } catch ( InterruptedException e ) {
            // this thread is regularly terminated via an interrupt
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
        }

    }
}
```

6) Also, don't forget to use this:

```
ProviderInstaller.installIfNeeded(getApplicationContext());
SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
sslContext.init(null, null, null);
mWebSocketClient.setWebSocketFactory(new DefaultSSLWebSocketClientFactory(sslContext));
mWebSocketClient.connect();
```

as shown above in my question.

Hope this will help others!)) if you have any questions - ask me)